# Make AJAX Callbacks work within an iterator

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Why isn't this working? Only the `success` call for first response is working.

```
for(i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {

    $.ajax({
        url : 'runTest.php',
        type : 'post',
        data : "testNumber="+i+"&url=" + testUrl,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {

        var row = $('<tr />');
            $('<td />').text(data.testName).appendTo(row);
            $('<td />').text(data.testSeverity).appendTo(row);
            $('<td />').text(data.testResult).appendTo(row);
            $('<td />').text(data.testResultDetail).appendTo(row);
            $('<td />').text(data.testDescription).appendTo(row);

            $('table#results tbody').append(row);

        }
    });

}
```

[image]

Comment: It might be returning a 304 not modified HTTP code, which might make success not called...?

Comment: It should work, though sending ajax requests in a loop can have performance problems.

Comment: Careful with `i`, it's leaking to global scope.

Comment: @Blazemonger Order doesn't matter to me

Comment: @jqueryrocks Good point, but still 3 of them are `200 OK`

Comment: As mentioned already, you really need to break open your browser tools and inspect the HTTP traffic going across the wire to see what response you get back from the server.

Comment: @jqueryrocks - Are you sure that a 403 doesn't call the success handler? That's surprising.

Comment: @KevinB I thought of the same, but only first call is working. The other calls are going through but success method is not triggering

Comment: @Joseph For 304 I'm not sure, I said "might"

Comment: @Josh added an image for reference

Comment: Maybe there's a problem on the server side? You're triggering the same PHP script six times at once; perhaps the SQL database is locking on the first one and the other five return SQL errors which you aren't checking for. In that case, you need to include some kind of `while...sleep` loop inside the PHP that waits until the database is available.

Comment: @Blazemonger you sir are right, I missed a `die;` statement in test 2 and test 3. Ok, so what do I do with this question now? Delete?

Comment: where is the testUrl value?? maybe is too long and make an invalid request? url GET request has normally of maximum request of 8192 bytes

Comment: @JosephSilber In the jQuery source code, there's this line that handles "successful": `if ( status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304 ) {`. So 304 is a success. I'm not sure why you said 403, but that's an error

Comment: @Blazemonger If will let it live here if you are posting an answer. It will be upto others then if they want to vote and close it.

Comment: @jqueryrocks 304 **does** call the success callback, at least in terms of jQuery's `ajax` method

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/yTaUL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a problem on the server side. You're triggering the same PHP script six times at once; perhaps the database (or whatever) is locking on the first request and the other five return errors which you aren't checking for. In that case, you need to include some kind of `while...sleep` loop inside the PHP that waits until the database is available.

Here's what I did for a similar problem, when I was using a PHP script to retrive data from Google Maps and was running into request limits. But the idea is simple enough, and you should be able to modify it for your own needs:

```
$params = http_build_query($_GET);
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?sensor=false&" . $params;

$json = file_get_contents($url);
$status = json_decode($json)->status;

// check for over_query_limit status
while ($status=="OVER_QUERY_LIMIT") {
    sleep(0.2); // seconds
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $status = json_decode($json)->status;
}
```

Comment: Oh @Blazemonger I am not using SQL here. Edits?